# Why does my sqlite selection return no results?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have added some records to my Android App Db.

Then I try to retrieve these rows but I'm always getting cursor set at position -1.

What is wrong with my syntax?

```
public class PhoneDal extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = Constants.DB_NAME;

    public static final String BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE = "BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE";

    public PhoneDal(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE "+ BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE +
                        " ( "+ KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1, "
                        + KEY_PHONE+" TEXT, "
                             + KEY_IS_BLOCKED+" BIT )";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            Log.w("MyAppTag", "Updating database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + " .Existing data will be lost.");
            // Drop older books table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE);

            // create fresh books table
            this.onCreate(db);
        }

    }



    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE = "KEY_PHONE";
    private static final String KEY_IS_BLOCKED = "KEY_IS_BLOCKED";

    public long addItem(Phone phone) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOGGER_TAG, "add saved-offer");
        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(KEY_ID, phone.id);
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, phone.phone);
        values.put(KEY_IS_BLOCKED, phone.isBlocked);

        // 3. insert
        long newRowId =
                db.insertWithOnConflict(BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE, KEY_ID,
                values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

        if (newRowId > 0) {
            final String text = String.format("item was added to table: %s",
                    BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE);
            Log.d(Constants.LOGGER_TAG, text);

        }

        // 4. close
        db.close();
        return newRowId;
    }

    public Phone getItem(String phone) {

        Phone result = null;

        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
                BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE,
                new String[] { KEY_ID  }, ""+KEY_PHONE+" = ? AND "+KEY_IS_BLOCKED+" = ?",
                new String[] { phone, "1" }, null, null, null);

        // 3. if we got results get the first one
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getPosition() != -1) {
            result = new Phone();
            result.id = (cursor.getInt(1));
            result.phone = phone;
            result.isBlocked = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

[image]

I have tried to create a select * query but yet got no results (cursor at position -1)

```
            BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE,
            new String[] { KEY_ID  },null, null, null, null, null);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature. When you query and receive a cursor, it always points to index -1 at first. You'll have to call one of the `moveTo...()` methods on it first before trying to access data. These methods return a boolean value that tells you if the cursor points to a valid row after te move.

For example, change this:

```
// 3. if we got results get the first one
if (cursor != null && cursor.getPosition() != -1) {
```

to something like

```
// 3. if we got results get the first one
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
```

`SQLiteDatabase` query methods never return a null so checking for one is sort of redundant.

Comment: so how will it look like where there are no results?

Comment: `moveTo...()` returns false.

Comment: so how would the while-do loop look like if I want to fetch all the cursor results?

Comment: Hint: Break the loop when the move fails.

Comment: yes, but do I need to moveToFirst or immidiately moveToNext (which works. but not sure if that's ok?)